# Full-text search all versions of a file using Subclipse

Tags: full-text-search, subclipse

How can I search for text in all versions of a single file? I removed a code block and cannot find it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion does not offer a text search feature of the repository. Subclipse is a Subversion client and relies on the Subversion API for everything.  So if Subversion does not support something, then neither does Subclipse.